# Not getting values in a view after join tables in controller, .Net Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I have joined four tables in a controller to get values in a view, but getting values for two tables: *productTypes* and *product_items* only.

```
var product_type = context.productTypes
                .Include(x => x.product_items)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.sub_product_items)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.customer)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Country)                
                .Where(x => x.product_typeId == id)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: OK.. What is your question?

Comment: have you checked whether the data is present or not. I m not sure but can you try Tolist()

Comment: Please add your Models and entity configurations.

Comment: @CaiusJard How can i get data from specific columns in fourth table to shown in the view ?

Comment: First you need to determine where the data is going missing..

Comment: (data here is probably either in: the db, the entity model, the viewmodel, the html/page controls in the client browser. You need to work through and find out where it goes missing. Start with the db)

Comment: data from sub_product_items , customer ,country  tables is missing in productview.cshtml  page  where after @items. brings data from first two tables only. i have problem in view page and all data are available in models.

Comment: If the data is in the model but not coming onto the page we really need to see the page code that is rendering the model